# How can I use Google Sheet data in a sidebar and also within a <script>?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, sidebar

I am currently working with the following tutorial to display google sheet data in the sidebar: https://yagisanatode.com/2018/02/12/how-to-get-something-from-google-sheets-and-display-it-in-the-sidebar-in-google-apps-script/#more-219

However, I would like to add a "for" loop in my html file to display a number of checkboxes (see code below). Ultimately, I want to change the number "16" to the "rangeResult" value from my spread sheet. Can you offer suggestions on how to do this?

**Code.gs - function**

```
function numEarlyRelease() {  
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1OF6Y1CTU9dkIgd1P-nw-5f2lqHSS5cGZytndwzJhw-o");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var numValues = ss.getRange('R19').getValue();
  return numValues;
}
```

**Page.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <base target="_top">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
  <body>
    <h3><script> document.write(new Date().toLocaleDateString()); </script></h3>

    <div id="rangeResult"></div>
    <script>
    function addRange(rangeStartEnd){ 
      $('#rangeResult').text(rangeStartEnd);
    };
    for (var i = 1; i <=16; i++) {
      document.write('<br><input type="checkbox" name="scores" id="i" value="i">'+ i);
    }

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addRange).numEarlyRelease();
    </script> 

    <br><input type="button" value="Submit Check-In" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />   
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Review templated HTML and printing scriptlets (if the number is known at load time and won't change). Otherwise, just create them in a success handler for an asynchronous call, just as you have already used a success handler.

Comment: Put the loop inside `addrow` function and use `i<=rangeStartEnd`

Comment: TheMaster, thank you for your comment! Inserting the loop into the function was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions! Below is my solution. (I've changed the names of some of the variables to fit my project.)

**Code.gs**

```
function earlyRelease(e) {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1OF6Y1CTU9dkIgd1P-nw-5f2lqHSS5cGZytndwzJhw-o");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var numValues = ss.getRange('R19').getValue();
  var studentName = ss.getSheetValues(20, 18, numValues, 1);

  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
      .setTitle('Early Release')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);  }

function earlyReleaseList() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1OF6Y1CTU9dkIgd1P-nw-5f2lqHSS5cGZytndwzJhw-o");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var numValues = ss.getRange('R19').getValue();
  var studentNames = ss.getSheetValues(20, 18, numValues, 1);
  return studentNames; }
```

**Page.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
    function addStudents(studentList){ 
      $('#rangeResult').text(studentList);

      document.write(new Date().toLocaleDateString());

      var students = [];
      //The following loop was added to the function
      for (var i = 0; i < studentList.length; i++) {
        document.write('<br><input type="checkbox" name="students" id="i" value="i">'+ studentList[i]);
      }
      //Also added the buttons to the function with document.write rather than html tags outside of the function
      document.write('<br><input type="button" value="Submit Early Release" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />');
      document.write('<input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />');
    };

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addStudents).earlyReleaseList();
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function call -

`google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addRange).numEarlyRelease();`

Means if function `numEarlyRelease()` returns a value, in this case `numValues`, it is available as argument to function `addRange()`. `addRange()` takes a parameter `rangeStartEnd`, so it'll have the value of `numValues`. You can use that however you like. As an example, if it is a number -

```
for (var i = 1; i <=rangeStartEnd; i++) {
  document.append('<br><input type="checkbox" name="scores" id="i" value="i">'+ i);
}
```

Note: Do not use `document.write()` unless you want to overwrite everything that is in page already.