# How can I collect data from multiple HTML checkboxes and input that data into a google sheet?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, sidebar

I am continuing work on a previous project: [Google Sheet Data in a Sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55202973/how-can-i-use-google-sheet-data-in-a-sidebar-and-also-within-a-script)

Now, I would like to retrieve the items that have been checked in the sidebar and return that data to the Code.gs file and ultimately the Google Sheet (see code below). Can you offer suggestions on how to do this?

Below, I am trying to add the checked items to the "students" array. I would then like the "Submit Early Release" button to send the "students" array to the Code.gs file. However, I am unsure how to push the checked items to the array properly.

**Page.html**

```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
><html>
>  <head>
>     <base target="_top">
>     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
>  </head>
>    <body>
>     <script>
>     function addStudents(studentList){ 
>       $('#rangeResult').text(studentList);
>       
>       document.write(new Date().toLocaleDateString());
>       
>       var students = [];
>       for (var i = 0; i < studentList.length; i++) {
>         document.write('<br><input type="checkbox" name="studentList[i]" id="i" value="i">'+ studentList[i]);
>       }
>       document.write('<br><input type="button" value="Submit Early Release" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />');
>       document.write('<input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />');
>     };
>     
>     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addStudents).earlyReleaseList();
>     </script>
>   </body>
></html>
```

Thank you for your help!

**Update**

Madhav, thank you for your suggestions. I've adapted your code to fit my scenario, but I'm still having trouble getting the array data back to the spreadsheet. Specifically, when I click the "Submit Early Release" button the sidebar closes but no data is written into the specified cell.  Would you mind taking a look?

**Page.html**

Added another "src=" line for jquery - not sure if this is needed???

Added "collectNames" function to get checked names and send them back

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
    function addStudents(studentList){ 
      $('#rangeResult').text(studentList);

      document.write(new Date().toLocaleDateString());

      //var students = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < studentList.length; i++) {
        document.write('<br><input type="checkbox" class="special" name='+ studentList[i]+ 'id="i" value="i">'+ studentList[i]);
      }
      document.write('<br><input type="button" value="Submit Early Release" onclick="collectNames()" />');
      document.write('<input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />');
    };

    function collectNames(){
      var students = [];
      var checkboxes=document.getElementsByClassName("special");  //get all checkboxes
      for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
        if(checkboxes[i].checked){
          students.push(checkboxes[i].getAttribute("name")); //if checked then push to array the value
        }
      }
      //now send the finalarray to the destination
      google.script.run.releasedStudents(students);
      google.script.host.close();
    };

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addStudents).earlyReleaseList();
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

**Code.gs**

```
function releasedStudents(values) {  
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1OF6Y1CTU9dkIgd1P-nw-5f2lqHSS5cGZytndwzJhw-o");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = ss.getRange('V20').getValue();
  cell.setValue(values);
}
```

Comment: There are many examples of sending data from a website to another. A common example is a form. It is much too broad for us to show you how to create and send an HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push checked items into the array, then the first thing you will need to ensure is that each checkbox carries the value it represents in some form or the other. Your code does attempt to do that but when you write

```
document.write('<br><input type="checkbox" name="studentList[i]" id="i" value="i">'+ studentList[i]);
```

the name attribute of each checkbox is always the same because it is a constant string ("studentList[i]") and not the value from the array, so it should be replaced with :

```
document.write('<br><input type="checkbox" class="special"name='+studentList[i]+ ' id="i" value="i">'+ studentList[i]);
```

Once we are done with the input , we should be able to collect values from the checked boxes only ..one way to do that is to assign a class to all the checkboxes so that they can later be accessed via getElementsByClassName() function.

Once obtained, the value attribute of only those checkboxes should be pushed to the array which have the checked property as true.

A slightly different code demonstrating this is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <button id="clickthis">Click this</button>


</body>
<script>

    var studentList=["nevil","ron","draco","harry"];
    var finalarray=[];

    function runmyfun(){

            var checkboxes=document.getElementsByClassName("special");  //get all checkboxes
        for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
            if(checkboxes[i].checked){

               finalarray.push(checkboxes[i].getAttribute("name"));      //if checked then push to array the value

            }
        }

        //now send the finalarray to the destination
       }


        document.getElementById("clickthis").onclick=function(){

        document.write(new Date().toLocaleDateString());


        for (var i = 0; i < studentList.length; i++) {
        document.write('<br><input type="checkbox" class="special"name='+studentList[i]+ ' id="i" value="i">'+ studentList[i]);   //concat properly
      }
       document.write('<br><input type="button" value="Submit Early Release" onclick="runmyfun()" />');
      document.write('<input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />');
     };


    </script>
</html>
```

I  hope this is what you were looking for and not something else.